# Angular2: Validations using md-input

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular2. Trying to implement validation in form. But, it doesn't worked for me. I tried this

```
<form #f='ngForm' (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f.form)">
  <md-card>
    <md-card-content>
      <div class="frm-ctrl form-group">
        <label>Phone Number :</label>
        <div class="wpr">
          <div class="icon">
            <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
          </div>
          <md-input ngModel #phonenumber="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="PersonInfo.phonenumber" name="phonenumber" class="ctrl-wpr__ctrl form-group"
            min-length="4" required></md-input>
          {{phonenumber.errors | json}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </md-card-content>
  </md-card>
</form>
```

Help me where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<md-input ngModel 
          #phonenumber="ngModel" 
          [(ngModel)]="PersonInfo.phonenumber" 
          name="phonenumber" class="ctrl-wpr__ctrl form-group"
          min-length="4" required></md-input>
```

change this to

```
<md-input #phonenumber="ngModel"              //<<<===removed ngModel
         [(ngModel)]="PersonInfo.phonenumber" 
          name="phonenumber" 
          class="ctrl-wpr__ctrl form-group"
          min-length="4" required></md-input>
```

To display error msg you can use this code,

```
<div [hidden]="phonenumber.valid || phonenumber.untouched" class="alert alert-danger">
      phonenumber is required
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for reply. I want to display an error message below to that textbox.

Comment: I tried as you said, but it is not working. It is not showing up error message

Comment: What you need to do is, you type in something in md-input and erase it completely (make it blank), you'll have an error msg. (I'm not sure if its not working with md-input, but it should work with `<input type=text>`). If it doesn't work please replace `md-input` by `<input type=text>` to check whether it works with `input type=text`.

Comment: Yeah it's working as you said. But, without typing anything and Tab out it has display error message.

Comment: remove `|| phonenumber.pristine` part.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124448/discussion-between-nnr-and-micronyks).

Comment: it's critical to add:
`="ngModel"`
to this:
`#phoneNumber`

If you just leave it like, #phoneNumber, you'll see your validation message visible, even, when the field is valid!